# XML doesn't match XSD BizTalk

Tags: xml, biztalk, xsd-validation

I am getting an error: **Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'ns0:BizTalk_Invoices_Root'., Line '1', Column '56'.**

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:BizTalk_Invoices_Root xmlns:ns0="ReceiveInvoices">
```

My XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:schema="ReceiveInvoices"                        
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"                                                                                                                                                                                                  
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="BizTalk_Invoices_Root">
<xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Might this just be a matter of the tag not being closed or self-closed?

Comment: Hi Jeff,  haven't posted the complete XSD and XML as it was just this part showing error.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this according to the targetNamespace in your XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ns0:BizTalk_Invoices_Root xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006">
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the XSD file . Could you now help me with this? The previous XSD file wasn't proper.

Comment: @Shivang  I'm not sure what you are asking now.  If the above solved your problem then mark it as an answer.  If it does not, add more details to your question using the edit link.  If you have a new question please post it as a new question.